# How to change parameter value inside an ActionLink on click in a Razor page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following table header which is actually an ActionLink:

```
<th>
    @Html.ActionLink("Country Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = "CountryName", CurrentSort = ViewBag.CurrentSort })
</th>
```

What I want to do is, whenever I click this ActionLink, the `sortOrder` value will change to `""` (empty string). If I again click on ActionLink, `sortorder` value will change back to `"CountryName"`. This means, the onclick event will act like a toggle for `sortOrder` value.

How can I achieve this?

Please note that I'm going to use the `sortOrder` value inside my controller method. Here's the controller method's code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string CurrentSort, int? page)
        {

            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageIndex = 1;
            pageIndex = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;

            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;

            sortOrder = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "CountryName" : sortOrder; 

            IPagedList<Country> countries = null;

            if (sortOrder.Equals(CurrentSort))
            {
                countries = db.Countries.OrderByDescending(c => c.CountryName).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
            }
            else
            {
                countries = db.Countries.OrderBy(c => c.CountryName).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
            }
            return View(countries);
        }
```

Comment: is above code not working for you?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad No. The ActionLink is not working as a toggle. It changes only once.

Comment: you have to use ``TempData`` because ``ViewBag`` value just persist from action to view

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Is it possible for you to provide a detailed answer regarding this? Basically, I've not worked extensively with ASP.NET MVC and Razor and the last time I worked in ASP.NET MVC it was almost 1.5 years back. So I forgot many things.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewBag` will just persisit from action to View, after that it will not be available, so if some other action gets called after Index, you will lose the last value which was sent as SortOrder.

The solution can be to use `TempData` which can be persisted between actions and multiple requests as well:

Change your action code to use `TempData`:

```
  TempData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;

  sortOrder = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "CountryName" : sortOrder;
```

and now in View use `TempData.Peek()` to read value so that value is persisted in the `TempData` for reading again:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Country Name", 
                  "Index", 
                  new 
                  { 
                     sortOrder = "CountryName", 
                     CurrentSort = TempData.Peek("CurrentSort") as String 
                  }
                 )
```

You complete action:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string CurrentSort, int? page)
 {

        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageIndex = 1;
        pageIndex = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;

        sortOrder = String.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentSort) ? "CountryName" : CurrentSort; 
        // toggling sort

        TempData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder; 
        // persisting selected Sort

        IPagedList<Country> countries = null;

        if (sortOrder.Equals(CurrentSort))
        {
            countries = db.Countries.OrderByDescending(c => c.CountryName).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
        else
        {
            countries = db.Countries.OrderBy(c => c.CountryName).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
        return View(countries);
 }
```

You can read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818493/MVC-Tempdata-Peek-and-Keep-confusion) about TempData and you may also read this about [ViewData,ViewBag and TempData in asp.net mvc](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem)

Comment: I'm getting compilation error. `CS0103:The name 'CurrentSort' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @Capt.JackSparrow sorry my typo mistake it is TempData key so we need to put in double quotes, if you see in intellsense it will tell you that ``Peek()`` takes string as parameter

Comment: Yes I figured it out and fixed it. But I still can't make it toggle between "CountryName" and "". It's behaving the same.

Comment: @Capt.JackSparrow you are using wrong variable in action, you need to check on ``CurrentSortOrder`` in action not ``sortorder`` let me edit my post

Comment: Vai, it's still not doing the toggle.